# Automatically choose a bandwidth in R

Tags: r, regression, smoothing, mse

I have a function that I have added noise to. I want to test a few smoothers, but for each smoother I want to minimise MSE. I know the underlying function, so how can I make R automatically choose the bandwidth that minimises the MSE?